# Java - Why is the output of this enum array null?

Tags: java, enums

I created an enum array like this:

```
 enum MyEnums {
        FIRST, SECOND, THIRD, FOURTH;
 }
 public class MyEnumsTest {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            MyEnums[] myEnums = new MyEnums[4];
            for(int i = 0; i< myEnums.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(myEnums[i]);
            }
     }
 }
```

But why is the output null, null, null and null? And how can I get the element by myEnums[i].FIRST?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're doing here is creating an array of `MyEnums`, and the default value is `null` (you haven't set the values in the array).

If you wanted to print out the enum values you can use the `values()` method:

```
for(MyEnums en : MyEnums.values()) {
    System.out.println(en);
}
```

or (more like your original code)

```
for(int i = 0; i < MyEnums.values().length; i++) {
    System.out.println(MyEnums.values()[i]);
}
```

This prints:

```
FIRST
SECOND
THIRD
FOURTH
```

Comment: thanks for your response, it is a quiz problem in my java lesson, I'm so confused that why the MyEnums[i] is null but I can use MyEnums[i].FIRST to get the element in this enum struct. It's so weird.

Comment: @ClarkQian It is because constants in an enum class are defined as `public static final` which means they belong to the enum/class itself (not the instance). Therefore you can access them even if an object is `null`. Take for example a class `Test` with 1 member `public static final String NAME = "a";`, you can create a variable like this `Test t = null;` but you can *still* call `t.NAME` and it will return `a`.

Comment: wow, I start to learn java one month ago, it is so amazing! thanks!